# How to find the IP address of the user who accessed my web application deployed using Azure App Service?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans

Recently, I deployed a web application using Azure App Service. It's in the free tier service plan. I would like to access the logs of this web application and the IP address of the users who accessed my web application. How to find this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to enable Application Insights and use Web server telemetry

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-data-retention-privacy

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-asp-net

Comment: Though note that Application Insights anonymizes users a bit, all IP addresses have the last octet set to 0.